# How to fix 'Cannot convert 'Tmp' to 'float' in initialization

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently learning about operator overloading and I wanted to overload both `operator<<` (to display all elements of tab property of my class) and `operator[]` (to get and set individual elements of this array).

I tried to remove overload of `operator<<` but it didn't change anything.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Tmp{
private:
    float *tab;
    int size,elemCount = 0;
public:
    Tmp(int size,float element = 0.0f){
        this -> size = size;
        tab = new float[size];
        for(int i = 0;i < size;i ++){
            tab[i] = element;
            elemCount++;
        }
        this -> tab = tab;
    }


    const float& operator[] (const int count) const;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp* obj);


    ~Tmp(){
        delete[] tab;
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp* obj){
        os << "Wartości tablicy:" << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<obj->size;i++){
            os<<obj->tab[i]<<endl;
        }
        return os;
}

const float& Tmp::operator[] (const int count) const {
    return tab[count];
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Tmp *a = new Tmp(2);
    cout<<a<<endl;

    float b = a[0]; //error here
    //cout<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be assigning value of first element of tab array to variable `b`, but instead I get a "cannot convert 'Tmp' to 'float' in initialization" error.

Comment: `this -> tab = tab;` has no effect. both `tab` variables are the same.

Comment: WTH are you trying to achieve there? Sounds like you have a serious XY-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```cpp
float b = a[0];
```

`a` is a `Tmp*` pointer, so `a[0]` is the same as `*(a+0)`. You are not invoking your overloaded `operator[]` at all, you are simply invoking pointer arithmetic and dereferencing, so you really are assigning a `Tmp` object to your `float` variable, hence the error.

You need to dereference the pointer before invoking the operator:

```cpp
float b = (*a)[0];
```

Or, you can call the operator directly, like any other class method:

```cpp
float b = a->operator[](0);
```

A better solution is simply to not use a pointer at all, especially since you are leaking the `Tmp` object anyway (you are not calling `delete a;`):

```cpp
Tmp a(2);
float b = a[0];
```

Also, your overloaded `operator<<` needs to accept the `Tmp`  object by reference, not by pointer.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Tmp{
private:
    float *tab;
    int size, elemCount = 0;
public:
    Tmp(int size, float element = 0.0f){
        this->size = size;
        tab = new float[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            tab[i] = element;
            ++elemCount;
        }
    }

    ~Tmp(){
        delete[] tab;
    }

    const float& operator[] (const int count) const;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp& obj);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp& obj){
    os << "Wartości tablicy:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i){
        os << obj.tab[i] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

const float& Tmp::operator[] (const int count) const {
    return tab[count];
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Tmp a(2);
    cout << a << endl;

    float b = a[0];
    //cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that your `Tmp` class is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it is missing a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to ensure the contents of your `tab` array are copied between `Tmp` objects correctly.

A better solution is to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and let the compiler manage the memory for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Tmp{
private:
    vector<float> tab;
public:
    Tmp(int size, float element = 0.0f)
        : tab(size, element)
    {
    }

    const float& operator[] (const int count) const;
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp& obj);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Tmp& obj){
    os << "Wartości tablicy:" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < obj.tab.size(); ++i){
        os << obj.tab[i] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

const float& Tmp::operator[] (const int count) const {
    return tab[count];
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    Tmp a(2);
    cout << a << endl;

    float b = a[0];
    //cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```